# Is it possible to rename the XSRF-TOKEN cookie that Laravel is creating?

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain, session-cookies

My Laravel application is hosted on the same domain name (one application on only one subdomain, the other one on multiple subdomains) as another web application that use a XSRF-TOKEN cookie. The two cookies are conflicting. Is there any way to rename Laravel's cookie to something like XSRF-TOKEN_Second?
I am using Laravel version 6.
I apologize if the question was asked before, couldn't find an answer.
Thanks!

---

My solution

The problem was, in .env APP_NAME had same value on both projects. Rename one and it will change the name of the session and no more conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your own token by modifying the response:

```
$response->headers->setCookie(
  new Cookie(
    'NEW-XSRF-TOKEN-NAME', 
    $request->session()->token(), 
    $this->availableAt(60 * $config['lifetime']),
    $config['path'], 
    $config['domain'], 
    $config['secure'], 
    false, 
    false, 
    $config['same_site'] ?? null
    )
);
```

And you should update your middleware for checking the new token. `X-XSRF-TOKEN`, as per their docs, is just there for developer convenience. However, I still urge you not to write your own csrf logic.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem with 2 laravel apps on the same domain that communicate with each other, eg:

```
https://example.com/store/
https://example.com/gateway/
```

The CSRF tokens were competing with each other. It turns out that the easiest way to fix it was to set the session cookie path in `config/session.php` as follows:

```php
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    // fixes conflicts between store and gateway CSRF tokens
    'path' => '/store/',
```

and the same on the gateway:

```php
    'path' => '/gateway/',
```

*Update*: It's actually better not to hardcode the session cookie path, so the `APP_URL` can be changed later without breaking. Here's the code update:

```php
    'path' => parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_PATH),
```